# Launch metadata driven app in android

Tags: android

I have a string that contains metadata information. Based on this info, how does my app launch a relevant app by understanding this metadata?

For example:

If the string contains an URL , when I click a button, it should automatically launch a Browser. If string has a link to audio file,  it should launch a media/audio player and start playing. In other words, the launched Application should be metadata driven..

Any light on this would be great.

Thanks,
codersnet

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `Intent` and provide it a `Uri` which Android can resolve implicitly. For example:

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/5");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or, for a website example:

```
Uri websiteUri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, websiteUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any applications with the proper intent filters registered will be able to handle these requests. If there are multiple applications, the user will be prompted to select one, i.e. if there are multiple web browsers installed, the user will be asked to select which browser to use.